# How to read touchscreen input from assembly on Surface with no OS (not under Windows)

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, hid, touchscreen

I don't know how to read input from the touchscreen from assembly (under no operating system).
7 months ago I bought a Microsoft Surface Studio 2+ and I absolutely love it, but I'd like to take things to the next level and boot my own assembly application. I have these ideas: that I could output the bits from the 8 bytes that make up a word in RAM, as light or dark grey squares, depending on whether they are 0 or 1, and literally touch (and toggle) them, thus changing the instruction or data; or that I could output the capacitive heatmap of the contact points in greyscale.

I tried to contact Microsoft and ask them for the documentation, but they told me they didn't have it, which makes sense, because, as I found out from the "Linux Surface" project, the touch controller is made by Intel (I tried finding a contact email for Intel as well, but I had no success). So, I ended up peering through the IPTS (Intel Precise Touch and Stylus) driver source code from the "Linux Surface" project. I tried following the code hierarchy, jumping from function definition to function definition, and I understood that in order to purely program in C or C++, some helper functions are provided by the Linux kernel that are written in assembly, but I haven't been able to follow the breadcrumbs until the end.
Taking full control of such a fine piece of machinery would be a dream come true, so here I am, asking for your help :-) How can you read input from the touchscreen from assembly?

Comment: What does "under no operating system" mean?  Isn't linux an OS?

Comment: Linux was only mentioned because it already has a driver that can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I'd like my application to be the only thing running, that is, boot it from UEFI

Comment: Touchscreens are HID devices. They are usually connected through USB, I2C or SPI. Microsoft has some indirect information about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchscreen-devices). The HID protocol is lengthy but it's public (you can find the HID and HID over I2C specs from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchscreen-protocol-implementation)). If the surface touchscreen is over an internal USB bus, you'll need to implement a USB driver or use the UEFI USB Support Protocol.

Comment: This one isn't USB. At least the linux driver works using the intel management engine.

Comment: "*How can you read input from the touchscreen from assembly?*" - The programming language really isn't relevant. The fact that you specify baremetal is more significant (e.g. interrupt and DMA services aren't automatically available). Seem like you haven't clearly identified the interface to this "*touchscreen*". Understanding the hardware is more than half the task. BTW "*read input*" is redundant.

Comment: @Jester [It depends on the exact model OP has](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/discussions/1305#discussioncomment-7641019). If the Microsoft Surface Studio 2+ is a newer model (maybe the SLS2 listed on the linked page), then they probably won't be using the IPTS but an SPI-HID controller.